# How can I create a function object in C

Tags: c, oop

I would like to create a wrapper for c functions, so that I can convert a function call of the form `ret = function(arg1,arg2,arg3);` into the form `/*void*/ function_wrapper(/*void*/);`. That is similar to function objects in C++ and boost bind.

Is this possible? how can I do it?

**Update:**

To explain in more details what I am looking for:

We start with this function:

```
int f(int i){
    //do stuff
    return somevalue;
}
```

Obvioulsy, it is called like this:

```
// do stuff
int x = 0;
ret = f(0);
// do more stuff.
```

I would like to do some magic that will wrap the function into `void function(void)`

```
struct function_object fo;
fo.function_pointer = &f;
fo.add_arg(x, int);
fo.set_ret_pointer(&ret);
fo.call();
```

**Note: I saw that there was a vote for closing this question and marking it as unclear. Please do not do that. I have a legitimate need to get this question answered. If you need explanation, ask and I will be glad to elaborate.**

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What exactly is your required relationship between `function` and `function2`?

Comment: It's not possible with exactly this syntax.

Comment: @kaylum: I think the OP wants `function2()` to be equivalent to `function(arg1, arg2, arg3)` (but `function2` should somehow depend on `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3`).

Comment: The price you pay for that in C++ is that a function is no longer a function - it is a function object. Functionality of `()` operator is implemented by a method with a hidden `this` parameter. You can implement all that explicitly/manually in C, but it won't look pretty. C lacks support for syntactic sugar that makes "calls" to function objects in C++ look superficially similar to regular function calls.

Comment: @KerrekSB I see. With enough plumbing I guess you could get the equivalent in C. Whether it's a good idea to do that or not is a different matter.

Comment: In a nutshell, the answer is no because C doesn't have an implicit "this" pointer.  `obj.call()` in C++ is passing `obj` as an unnamed argument.  In C the syntax to get the same thing is (obviously) `call(obj)`. If you allow that, then you can get what you want.

Comment: Is `ret somevalue;` supposed to be `return somevalue;`?

Comment: "I want an answer" is not a valid reason not to close the question. "I [edit]ed my question to no longer be off-topic" is. Do that. Right now, there's no explanation of what you mean by "convert it to `void f(void)`"; you just give pseudocode of how it would happen. Where are the arguments going to come from, for example?

Comment: @Keith Thompson yes, I fixed that in the question. The focus is on the idea of the question though. I do not care of that pseudo code had typos or not.

Comment: @Gene I do not not having a this pointer in C would be a problem. We can pass the pointer of the struct function_object using a special function in worst case scenario. for example 'fo.set_this_pointer(&fo)'

Comment: @QPaysTaxes thanks for the inquiry. I did add an example to explain in more details what I am looking for. Besides, anyone knows C++ knows what I am talking about. Function objects and boost bind are well known.

Comment: In your "Obvioulsy" code sample, is `ret = f(0);` supposed to be `ret = f(x`);`? (Details like that do matter to people who are trying to understand what you're asking.)

Comment: @hebbo You're not getting it.  If `call()` has no arguments, the only stuff it can access is local vars and global vars. It has no way to access the field of a `struct` (unless it's a global, possibly static).  You can't fake a unnamed `this` object pointer in a language that doesn't implement them.

Comment: How many "different" functions are to be wrapped? I mean, how different can they be to each other? If they fall in a finite number of categories, for example "int(int), int(int,int), int(int,int,int)" (3 different signatures/categories), then it should be perfectly viable.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with a better code that might allow you to do what you want. First I'll explain how it works, show the code and explain why I still don't think it's a good idea to use it (though the code might open doors for improvements that addresses those issues).

#### Functionality:

- Before you start using the "function objects", you have to call an initialization function (`FUNCTIONOBJ_initialize();`), which will initialize the mutexes on every data structure used in the library.
- After initializing, every time you want to call one of those "function objects", without using the parameters, you will have to set it up first. This is done by creating a `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t` pointer and calling `get_function_handler()`. This will search for a free `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler` data structure that can be used at the moment.
- If none is found (all `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler` data structures are busy, being used by some function call) `NULL` is returned.
- If `get_function_handler()` does find a `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler` data structure it will try to lock the `FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder` data structure, that holds the `ID` of the `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler` of the function **about to be called**.
- If `FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder` is locked already, `get_function_handler()` will hang until it's unlocked by the thread using it.
- Once `FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder` is locked, the ID of the grabbed `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler` is wrote on it and the `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler` pointer is returned by `get_function_handler`.
- With the pointer in hand, the user can set the pointer to the arguments and the return variable with `set_args_pointer` and `set_return_pointer`, which both take a `void *` as arguments.
- Finally, you can call the function you want. It has to:

  1 - Grab the `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler` `ID` from the `FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder` data structure and use it to get a pointer to the `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler` itself.

  2 - Use the `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler` to access the arguments.

  3 - Return by using one of the return function (on the example we have `ret_int`, which will return an integer and unlock the `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler`)

Below is a simplified mind map describing a bit of what is going on:

[image: Mind map]

Finally, the code:

**funcobj.h**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_CALLS 1024

typedef struct {
    //Current ID about to be called
    int current_id;

    //Mutex
    pthread_mutex_t id_holder_mutex;
} FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder_t; 

typedef struct {
    //Attributes
    void *arguments;
    void *return_pointer;

    //Mutex
    pthread_mutex_t handler_mutex;
} FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t;

FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t FUNCTIONOBJ_handler[MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_CALLS];
FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder_t FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder;

void set_return_pointer(FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t *this, void *pointer);
void set_args_pointer(FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t *this, void *pointer);
void ret_int(FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t *this, int return_value);
void FUNCTIONOBJ_initialize(void);
FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t *get_function_handler(void);
```

**funcobj.c**:

```
#include "funcobj.h"

void set_return_pointer(FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t *this, void *pointer){
    this->return_pointer = pointer;
}

void set_args_pointer(FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t *this, void *pointer){
    this->arguments = pointer;
}

void ret_int(FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t *this, int return_value){
    if(this->return_pointer){
        *((int *) (this->return_pointer)) = return_value;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(this->handler_mutex));
}

void FUNCTIONOBJ_initialize(void){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_CALLS; ++i){
        pthread_mutex_init(&FUNCTIONOBJ_handler[i].handler_mutex, NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_init(&FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder.id_holder_mutex, NULL);
}

FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t *get_function_handler(void){
    int i = 0;

    while((0 != pthread_mutex_trylock(&FUNCTIONOBJ_handler[i].handler_mutex)) && (i < MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_CALLS)){
        ++i;
    }
    if(i >= MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_CALLS){
        return NULL;
    }

    //Sets the ID holder to hold this ID until the function is called
    pthread_mutex_lock(&FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder.id_holder_mutex);
    FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder.current_id = i;

    return &FUNCTIONOBJ_handler[i];
}
```

**main.c**:

```
#include "funcobj.h"

#include <string.h>

//Function:
void print(void){
    //First the function must grab the handler that contains all its attributes:
    //The FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder is mutex locked, so we can just access its value and
    //then free the lock:
    FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t *this = &FUNCTIONOBJ_handler[FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder.current_id];
    //We dont need the id_holder anymore, free it!
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder.id_holder_mutex);

    //Do whatever the function has to do
    printf("%s\n", (char *) this->arguments);

    //Return the value to the pointed variable using the function that returns an int
    ret_int(this, 0);
}

void *thread_entry_point(void *data){
    int id = (int) data;

    char string[100];
    snprintf(string, 100, "Thread %u", id);

    int return_val;

    FUNCTIONOBJ_handler_t *this;

    for(int i = 0; i < 200; ++i){
        do {
            this = get_function_handler();
        } while(NULL == this);

        set_args_pointer(this, string);
        set_return_pointer(this, &return_val);
        print();
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    //Initialize global data strucutres (set up mutexes)
    FUNCTIONOBJ_initialize();

    //testing with 20 threads
    pthread_t thread_id[20];

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
        pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, &thread_entry_point, (void *) i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i){
        pthread_join(thread_id[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To compile: `gcc -o program main.c funcobj.c -lpthread`

#### Reasons to avoid it:

- By using this, you are limiting the number of "function objects" that can be running simultaneously. That's because we need to use global data structures to hold the information required by the functions (arguments and return pointer).
- You will be seriously slowing down the program when using multiple threads if those use "function objects" frequently: Even though many functions can run at the same time, only **a single** function object can be set up at a time. So at least for that fraction of time it takes for the program to set up the function and actually call it, all other threads trying to run a function will be hanging waiting the the data structure to be unlocked.
- You still have to write some non-intuitive code at the beginning and end of each function you want to work without arguments (grabbing the `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler` structure, unlocking the `FUNCTIONOBJ_id_holder` structure, accessing arguments through the pointer you grabbed and returning values with non-built-in functions). This increases the chances of bugs drastically if care is not taken, specially some nasty ones:
- Increases the chances of **deadlocks**. If you forget to unlock one of the data structures in any point of your code, you might end up with a program that works fine at some moments, but randomly freeze completely at others (because all function calls without arguments will be hanging waiting for the lock to be freed). That is a risk that happens on multithreaded programs anyways, but by using this you are increasing the amount of code that requires locks unnecessarily (for style purposes).
- Complicates the use of recursive functions: Every time you call the function object you'll have to go through the set up phrase (even when inside another function object). Also, if you call the recursive function enough times to fill all `FUNCTIONOBJ_handler` structures **the program will deadlock**.
- Amongst other reasons I might not notice at the moment :p

Comment: Good work. I will take a look over the weekend. This needs a careful eye to look at. :)